# How to mount an external volume on a Linux virtual instance?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04, volume, mount

I have launched an instance from Ubuntu 18.04 image and attached a volume at /dev/vdc. I am not sure how I can mount it to media/data.

Answer (score 2):

**Found the solution**

Create a partition on the volume with

```
[name@server ~]$ sudo fdisk /dev/vdb
```

fdisk will prompt you to enter a command. Use this sequence of single-character commands to create a new partition on your volume.

```
n => new partition
p => primary, only one partition on disk
1 => partition number 1
<return> => first sector (use default)
<return> => last sector (use default)
w => write partition table to disk and exit
```

Format the newly created partition with

```
[name@server ~]$ sudo mkfs -t ext4 /dev/vdb1
```

Create a place to mount the device with

```
[name@server ~]$ sudo mkdir /media/data
```

Finally, mount the volume with

```
[name@server ~]$ sudo mount /dev/vdb1 /media/data
```

If the VM is rebooted for some reason the volume will need to be remounted. To cause the VM to mount the volume automatically at boot time, edit `/etc/fstab` and add a line like

```
 /dev/vdb1 /media/data ext4 defaults 0 2
```

[name@server ~]$ sudo mount -a